# Assign values from a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, assign

I have a data frame with "i" columns and want to run "j" regressions on each of the columns vs. an extracted component from another function (cluster_simple), returning a vector such that:

```
print(RSquared_1)
[1] "rsquared value 1" "rsquared value 2" "etc,"
```

To do this, I have two loops:

```
for (i in 1:columns)
  {assign(paste("Rsquared_",i,sep="",collapse=NULL),
            #Assign these values from this loop 
            for (j in 1:iterations) 
              { exp<-cluster_simple(frame,number,noprint=T)
                reg<-lm(exp[,'clusters']~exp[,i])
                rsq[j]<-summary(reg)$r.squared
              }
          )
  }
```

So far both loops work great on their own, but I can't get the value to be assigned to the variable, I end up with:

```
print(RSquared_1)
NULL
```

Is there some specific function I need to apply in the assign?

Comment: Using `assign` is your first mistake. That's what pre-allocated lists are for. Why are you calculating `cluster_simple()` each time, it doesn't appear to change...? How many R2 values are you doing? The inner for loop with create `iterations` of them (and where was `rsq` created?), how should the `iterations` R2 values be collapsed down to single value for each `i`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to use assign because the number of columns ("i") will change with every dataframe (I cant have a fixed amount of variables to list). cluster_simple() has a random component, which is why i'm running a lot of regressions multiply times. About 1,000 rsquared variables. Ultimately what I want is a vector with all the rsquared values assigned to RSquared_columnnumber

Comment: You don't need to use `assign`. The size of each data frame can be determined programmatically, and used to create a list of the appropriate length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is `i` collections of `j` r squared values, you can do something much simpler.

This regresses a vector returned by `cluster_sample`  on each `i`, `j` times. Output is a list of length `i`, each item of which is `j` r squared values.

```
n <- 20 # rows
i <- 10 # columns
j <- 5 # iterations

# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n*i), ncol=i))

# dummy function
cluster_simple <- function() rnorm(n)

# regress cluster_simple on each column i, j times
r_sq_list <-
  lapply(1:i, function(ii) {
    sapply(1:j, function(jj) {
      summary(lm(cluster_simple() ~ dat[,ii]))$r.squared
    })
  })


# get the r_sq for the 7th column regression, 3rd iteration
r_sq_list[[7]][3]
```